# What is the process to migrate a question to another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, migration

Prior to the editing attempt to shoehorn it into a format that works on Bicycles SE, [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14956/does-the-us-only-patent-on-the-four-bar-linkage-horst-link-suspension-affect-p) would have been a good fit for Patents SE. I've suggested a rollback to make it a good fit for their site but I don't know how the migration process works. How would I suggest that it get migrated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic process:

1. Verify that the question is constructive, clear, and generally a good Stack Exchange style question.
2. Verify that the question would be on-topic on the other site. If you're not active on the other site, read the [first part of their faq](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#askpatents) where site scope is laid out. If it seems at all borderline, you may want to ask on [their meta](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com) or [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4734/patents).
3. If the question is on-topic on our site, you'll want to try to get the original questioner on-board with a migration (comment asking if they want it migrated).
4. If the question is *good* and *on-topic* for the other site, depending on your reputation, you can either use "close">"off-topic">"belongs on another site" and enter the site you think it belongs on, or "flag">"it doesn't belong here">"off-topic" and enter the site it belongs on.

We don't have any sites that we've migrated a lot of things to, so there's nothing in the site list other than our own meta. That means it always ends up turning into a flag for the moderators to deal with.

If your rep is over 3,000, please consider checking the [review](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/review) queue every once in a while for Close Votes and Reopen Votes. That can help things to happen without moderator intervention. As mod, I'm happier migrating a question that has a couple "please migrate me" votes than one with nothing.

This only applies to questions asked in the last couple months. It's not possible to migrate older questions.