# Suggested migration sites

Tags: support, migration

After [freiheit's](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/76/freiheit) [answer](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/807/4239) to [this question](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/what-is-the-process-to-migrate-a-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site), I thought I might ask the community for suggestions for sites to be added to our migration list.

One suggestion per answer please. That way the community can vote up or down whether they think the suggestion is a good one.

Comment: We get some incoming migrations from [travel.se] and [outdoors.se]. We've migrated to both of those, plus [physics.se]. Once we migrated a post to [electronics.se]. Honestly the number of outgoing migrations is small enough that it's no problem for mods to handle it.

Comment: I was actually thinking that not only would it make it easier for the mods, but that we might actually get more outgoing migrations if the process were more streamlined. Not that I want people off our site; I just want people's questions in the place where they'll get the best answers. It also could prevent future kerfuffles like the one surrounding the Horst link question.

Comment: Can we reactive / re-energize this idea please? The close reasons popup only offers *Meta* as an option.

Comment: Many years later, and i'm still only seeing Meta as a migration option.  Did anything ever happen with this?

Answer (score 6):

There was a question that was recently migrated to [Fitness SE](http://fitness.stackexchange.com). This seems like an obvious fit for our migration list. Even though training regimens are unique for cyclists, there are some questions that are more universally applicable to all endurance athletes; questions about diet and cross training are what immediately come to mind.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tag "cycling" in [Sports SE](https://sports.stackexchange.com/) with questions about professional cycling. Some fit equally well on both, it seems that some of them could be even moved here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure that I've seen a couple of GPS questions that had been migrated to [Geographic Information Systems SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com). Along those same lines, it's easy to imagine touring questions that would be a better fit for [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: One link per answer please! I'd upvote travel but not GIS.

Comment: @RoboKaren Doh! I wrote the question but broke my own rule! And now I don't think I can divide it up since I don't know if that would effect existing votes. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a number of questions on this site that could fit in [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com) just as well as they fit on our site. Some fit equally well on both, but it's easy to envision one that truly belongs over there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see migration to [Health.SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/) -- we have a decent number of health oriented questions.

Answer (score 0):

Question that are mainly about software selection and barely about bicycles could fit better at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).